# Best way how to validate field when insert/update

Tags: sql-server, validation, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to apply custom validation using CHECK + UDF, nonetheless, it doesn't work properly in my case, moreover after searching there is an opinion that such approach may impact performance and it is not robust.

Is in the T-SQL some existing tools to resolve my issue?

Here is my sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.test_name_uniq;

CREATE TABLE dbo.test_name_uniq (
  name VARCHAR(255),
  state VARCHAR(255)
)
  
ALTER TABLE dbo.test_name_uniq DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS test_name_uniq_constraint;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.validate_test_name_uniq;

GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.validate_test_name_uniq(@name VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS BIT
AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @unique_name BIT = 0;
    SELECT @unique_name = CASE
                          WHEN COUNT(*) > 0
                            THEN 0
                          ELSE 1
                          END
    FROM dbo.test_name_uniq i
    WHERE i.name = @name AND i.state <> 'Removed';
    RETURN @unique_name;
  END;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.test_name_uniq
  WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT test_name_uniq_constraint CHECK (dbo.validate_test_name_uniq(name) = 1 );
GO

DELETE FROM dbo.test_name_uniq;

GO
INSERT INTO dbo.test_name_uniq (name, state) VALUES
  ('Test application', 'Active');
```

Every time when I try to insert a row, I get the error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "test_name_uniq_constraint". The conflict occurred in database "data_local_test", table "dbo.test_name_uniq", column 'name'.

Comment: The constrain is checking the result of function validate_inventory, not validate_test_name_uniq

Comment: @Jayvee, it's a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: Syntax is not even valid on my server

Comment: Tip: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with a [*UNIQUE FILTERED INDEX*](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/whats-good-use-unique-filtered-index) on column `name` where `state<>'Removed'`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uix_name
ON dbo.test_name_uniq (name)
WHERE where state<> 'Removed';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I think it should be `where state<> 'Removed'`, but +1 anyway.

Comment: Indeed, that would be the best approach. I assumed there are just two possible values for `state`, but that may not be true. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is the same as the intent of the OP.  This allows multiple unique.  OP only wants one other as I read it.